# Matlab legend colors don't match lines

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, matlab-figure

Not sure what is going wrong here. I created a minimal example below:

```
clear
steps = 1:6;
labels = cell(length(steps),1);
xvals = 1:10;
fig = figure(1);
ax = axes('parent',fig);
hold on
for ii=1:length(steps)
    s=steps(ii);
    yvals = zeros(length(xvals)) + ii;
    labels{ii} = ['gain = ' num2str(s)];
    plot(ax,xvals,yvals);
end
legend(ax, labels);
hold off
```

And the result on my system is:

[image: Wrong plot colors]

With less lines it can even put colors in the legend that aren't even on the plot. What is happening?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation of what's happening

The problem is in the line

> `yvals = zeros(length(xvals)) + ii;`

This creates a 10x10 square **matrix**, not a 1x10 vector. [`plot`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) then plots each **column** of that matrix against `xvals`. That causes a mixing up of colors which is probably not what you want.

It's interesting to analyze specifically what happens. Matlab plots each column of that matrix with a different color, using the [default cycle of colors](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/why-are-plot-lines-different-colors.html), which in Matlab R2014b onwards is

[image]

But all columns of that matrix are the same, so each covers (overwrites) the preceding one, and you only see the **last** color.

Now, the color cycle has 7 colors and the matrix has 10 columns. So in the first iteration the last plotted column (the one you see) has color `mod(10,7)==3` (yellow). In the second iteration you cycle through 10 more colors starting from `3`, that is, you get color `mod(3+10,7)==6` (light blue). And so on. Thus the color you see in the figure depends on the loop index `ii`, but not in the way you expected.

[`legend`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html) creates its entries by picking the color (and line spec) of each plotted line, in the order in which they were plotted. There are `10*6==60` plotted lines, each corresponding to a column of a matrix. But since you only supply six strings to `legend`, it just picks the **first six** of those lines, and uses their colors to create the legend entries. Those colors follow the default order, as explained above.

None of those first six lines that make it into the legend are actually seen in the figure, because they are covered by other lines. But `legend` doesn't care about that. So you get six legend entries with the default color order, which of course doesn't match the lines you actually see in the graph.

### Solution

From the above, the solution is clear: replaced the referred line by

```
yvals = zeros(1, length(xvals)) + ii;
```

to create `yvals` as a **vector** (not a matrix). That way you'll get the figure you expected:

[image]