# Matlab legend colors don't match lines (2)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, legend, legend-properties

I'm experiencing the same problem as on this thread:

[Matlab legend colors don't match lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661902/matlab-legend-colors-dont-match-lines)

However, no variation of the solution proposed seems to work on my code...

My code is:

```
thickness = [0.0254,0.05,0.075,0.1,0.127];
for i = 1:5
    [~,t,u] = Shuttle(4000,501,thickness(i),21,'crank-nicolson',false,'597');
    T = u(:,1);
    figure(2);
    plot(t,T);
    y{i} = ['Thickness = ' num2str(x(end))];
    hold all
end

hold off
xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Inner Surface Temperature (deg C)')
legend(y);
```

Where Shuttle basically solves for the temperature along a profile with certain initial conditions, and by plotting u(:,1) it takes the final/ end-point values for temperature and im trying to plot it for a variety of overall lengths.

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Comment: try `h(i) = plot(t,T);` in the loop and `legend(h,y);` in the end